how to control two switch separate in thingsboard iot using esp32
Thingsboard , I'm having trouble with two switch. I'm trying to integrate a switch widget into the dashboard so that I can control two led, but two switch in the same function i dont know why.
i noted have done when one switch work fine.
this my code
RPC_Response setLedStatus(const RPC_Data &data);
RPC_Response setLedStatus_2(const RPC_Data &data);
void processTime(const JsonVariantConst& data);

// Define the array of RPC callbacks
const std::array<RPC_Callback, 2U> callbacks = {
RPC_Callback{ "setLedStatus", setLedStatus },
RPC_Callback{ "setLedStatus_2", setLedStatus_2 }
}; 
if (!tb.connected()) {
 connectToThingsBoard();
// Subscribe to RPC callbacks
 Serial.println("Subscribing for RPC...");
 if (!tb.RPC_Subscribe(callbacks.cbegin(), callbacks.cend())) {
 //  Serial.println("Failed to subscribe for RPC");
   return;
  }

  }
  // Request the current time if not already subscribed





  // Request the current time if not already subscribed
   if (!subscribed) {
  //  Serial.println("Requesting RPC...");
   RPC_Request_Callback timeRequestCallback("getCurrentTime", processTime);
   if (!tb.RPC_Request(timeRequestCallback)) {
   // Serial.println("Failed to request for RPC");
    return;
    }
    //Serial.println("Request done");
    //subscribed = true;
     }
     tb.loop();
   RPC_Response setLedStatus(const RPC_Data &data) {
   // Process the RPC request to change the LED state

    int dataInt = data;
    ledState = dataInt == 1;  // Update the LED state based on the received data
    Serial.println(ledState ? "LED ON" : "LED OFF");

    return RPC_Response("setLedStatus", dataInt);  // Respond with the new status
        }

     RPC_Response setLedStatus_2(const RPC_Data &data) {
      // Process the RPC request to change the LED state

       int dataInt = data;
       ledState_2 = dataInt == 1;  // Update the LED state based on the received data
       Serial.println(ledState_2 ? "LED_2 ON" : "LED_2 OFF");

         return RPC_Response("setLedStatus_2", dataInt);  // Respond with the new status
           }

control 2 switch seprately wih led
